# rails devise sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How can I set the http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in as http://localhost:3000 so that it becomes the root path if the user is not logged_in right now i am using

```
 authenticate :user do
    root :to => "home#index"
 end
```

Now if the user is not authenticated it takes to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in but I need it as http://localhost:3000 is there any possibility of doing this I also tried using devise_for by setting the path as empty like this

```
             devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names => {:sign_in => ''}
```

But I think this is not the exact way of doing. plz help me in this thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you want. Do you want the root path to be accessible for non-authenticated users, or do you want them to automatically be redirected to the sign_in page?